# Pick and resize image flow, how to implement it fluently

Tags: flutter

I need to provide a flow for the user to pick an image, resize it and store it.
I have the user profile picture with a `InkWell` and the following `onTap` method

```
var original = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
if (original == null) return;
File croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
   sourcePath: original.path,
   aspectRatioPresets: [CropAspectRatioPreset.square],
   androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
       toolbarColor: Palette.primary,
       lockAspectRatio: false),
   iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
   minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
));
if (croppedFile != null) upload(croppedFile);
```

This works fine. However the `ImagePicker` and the `ImageResizer` are two different plugins and two different flows. I need to `await` the first and then move to the second.

This creates a weird behaviour for the user. While moving from picker to resizer the screen goes back for few seconds to the main `UserPage`

How can I avoid that? How can I make these two plugins' flow fluently move one from each other without this small time-frame?

I guess this is due to the picker frame being removed from the stack and then the resizer one being added.

Comment: Maybe push another background image first? Then the user wouldn't see the `UserPage`.